# Python method dir() does not return all attributes/methods

Tags: python, attributes, dir

I have this piece of code (from Dive in Python 3):

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> tree = etree.parse("feed.xml")
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> print(dir(root))
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'extend', 'find', 'findall', 'findtext', 'get', 'getchildren', 'getiterator', 'insert', 'items', 'iter', 'iterfind', 'itertext', 'keys', 'makeelement', 'remove', 'set']
>>>
```

Several attributes are missing from the list, notably "tag", "text", "attrib", etc.

Why is this? How can I reliably get the complete list of attributes and methods from an objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are actually defined as the arguments accepted by the `getattr` built-in function. As the user can reimplement `__getattr__`, suddenly allowing any kind of attribute, there is no possible generic way to generate that list. The `dir` function returns the keys in the `__dict__` attribute, i.e. all the attributes accessible if the `__getattr__` method is not reimplemented.

Comment: the "root" object does not have the __dict__ attribute. Could it be that this is a native C implementation

Comment: Each `root` element has an attribute `.attrib`, which is a `dict`. You could access it like so: `print root.attrib`. [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element)